# Laravel Schedule Task Output

Tags: laravel

As per documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#task-output

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->daily()->sendOutputTo($filePath);
```

I set the file path

```
$schedule->command('word:day')->hourly()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/test_logos.log'));
```

But log file is empty? Cant see task output

Command Code

```
public function handle()
{
 $this->info('Word of the Day sent to All Users');
}
```

Comment: Do you get any output when running the command manually? Can you show the command's code?

Comment: @Jerodev edited my question to add command code