# Laravel scheduler task does not log the command's output in telescope

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom Laravel 6 command, and a scheduled task to execute that command. I expect that the command output get's logged in telescope (section "Scheduler" and details about a specific task), but actually only the command invocation is logged without any output.

The logging of output works well for a scheduled task of the built-in `telescope:prune` command.

Invoking my custom command from cli gives me the expected output.

This is my custom command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class FixBulkBillGraphicTicketsWorkaround extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'workarounds:fixBulkBillGraphicTickets';
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Moo foo');
    }
}
```

The `$this->info()` call is what the telescope-prune command implementation does as well. And as expected, it works fine from the cli:

```
$ php artisan workarounds:fixBulkBillGraphicTickets
Moo foo
```

The scheduler task definition:

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('telescope:prune --hours=168')
            ->everyMinute();

        $schedule->command('workarounds:fixBulkBillGraphicTickets')
            ->everyMinute();
    }
```

The `Moo foo` is not logged in telescope, but the output of the telescope:prune command is.

This question here might look similar to [Laravel Schedule Task Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253846/laravel-schedule-task-output) but there they talk about logging to log files.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentaion on task output and task hooks? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#task-output

Comment: Yeah I did, but these are talking about redirecting to logs or mails. I had a look at the telescope-prune command implementation, and it simply uses $this->info to output info, so I did the same in my implementation, but it does not work.

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is more going on with the telescope package than meets the eye. have you dug into the core code of that package to take a look?